# Switching from Debian 6 Squeeze stable to testing version

Tags: debian, kernel, gnome, upgrade

I had [this problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/24432) and I asked some friends of mine and their advice was to upgrade from my messed-up Debian Squeeze system to the testing version. So I did it. First I changed the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file to use testing repositories. Then I used `sudo apt-get update` and after that `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. After a long hour everything was upgraded (I suppose). Then I saw that system warning for restarting the system. Done.

First thing after the restart that surprised me was the GRUB loader. There were not just the 2 choices for `Debian 2.6.x.x` and `Debian 2.6.x.x (recovery)` but also the new versions `Debian 3.0.xx` (first in the grub list) and `Debian 3.0.xx`. I selected the `Debian 3.0.xx` and then the whole screen messed-up. Just some colorful pixels and nothing clear to see. Does anyone have any idea how can I cope with it?

P.S. If I select the Debian 2.6.xx it is working (lets say properly) but the design is changed and I have no System menu top-left any more + I don't have right mouse click on the desktop.

As Gilles suggested I am posting the output from `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`

```
maistora@maistora:~$ vi /boot/grub/grub.cfg 


#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  load_env
fi
set default="0"
if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}

function load_video {
  insmod vbe
  insmod vga
  insmod video_bochs
  insmod video_cirrus
}

insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 94dc5612-177b-4222-b426-f9fa5bad2664
if loadfont /usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2 ; then
  set gfxmode=640x480
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  insmod part_msdos
  insmod ext2
  set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 94dc5612-177b-4222-b426-f9fa5bad2664
  set locale_dir=($root)/boot/grub/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
set timeout=5
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 94dc5612-177b-4222-b426-f9fa5bad2664
insmod png
if background_image /usr/share/images/desktop-base/spacefun-grub.png; then
  set color_normal=light-gray/black
  set color_highlight=white/black
else
  set menu_color_normal=cyan/blue
  set menu_color_highlight=white/blue
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 3.0.0-1-686-pae' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 94dc5612-177b-4222-b426-f9fa5bad2664
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.0.0-1-686-pae ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-1-686-pae root=UUID=94dc5612-177b-4222-b426-f9fa5bad2664 ro  quiet
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-1-686-pae
}
menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 3.0.0-1-686-pae (recovery mode)' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 94dc5612-177b-4222-b426-f9fa5bad2664
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.0.0-1-686-pae ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-1-686-pae root=UUID=94dc5612-177b-4222-b426-f9fa5bad2664 ro single
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-1-686-pae
menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 2.6.32-5-686' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 94dc5612-177b-4222-b426-f9fa5bad2664
        echo    'Loading Linux 2.6.32-5-686 ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-5-686 root=UUID=94dc5612-177b-4222-b426-f9fa5bad2664 ro  quiet
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-5-686
}
menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 2.6.32-5-686 (recovery mode)' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 94dc5612-177b-4222-b426-f9fa5bad2664
        echo    'Loading Linux 2.6.32-5-686 ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-5-686 root=UUID=94dc5612-177b-4222-b426-f9fa5bad2664 ro single
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-5-686
}
### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

lspci

```
maistora@maistora:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 671MX
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] PCI-to-PCI bridge
00:02.0 ISA bridge: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] SiS968 [MuTIOL Media IO] (rev 01)
00:02.5 IDE interface: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 5513 [IDE] (rev 01)
00:03.0 USB Controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] USB 1.1 Controller (rev 0f)
00:03.1 USB Controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] USB 1.1 Controller (rev 0f)
00:03.3 USB Controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] USB 2.0 Controller
00:04.0 Ethernet controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 191 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter (rev 02)
00:05.0 IDE interface: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] SATA Controller / IDE mode (rev 03)
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] PCI-to-PCI bridge
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] PCI-to-PCI bridge
00:0f.0 Audio device: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] Azalia Audio Controller
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc Mobility Radeon HD 3400 Series
02:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR928X Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
```

dpkg -l linux-image-*

```
maistora@maistora:~$ dpkg -l linux-image-\*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                   Version                                Description
+++-======================================-======================================-============================================================================================
un  linux-image-2.6                        <none>                                 (no description available)
un  linux-image-2.6-486                    <none>                                 (no description available)
ii  linux-image-2.6-686                    3.0.0+39                               Linux for modern PCs (dummy package)
un  linux-image-2.6-686-bigmem             <none>                                 (no description available)
un  linux-image-2.6-amd64                  <none>                                 (no description available)
un  linux-image-2.6-k7                     <none>                                 (no description available)
un  linux-image-2.6-openvz-686             <none>                                 (no description available)
un  linux-image-2.6-vserver-686            <none>                                 (no description available)
un  linux-image-2.6-vserver-686-bigmem     <none>                                 (no description available)
un  linux-image-2.6-xen-686                <none>                                 (no description available)
ii  linux-image-2.6.32-5-686               2.6.32-38                              Linux 2.6.32 for modern PCs
ii  linux-image-3.0.0-1-686-pae            3.0.0-3                                Linux 3.0.0 for modern PCs
ii  linux-image-686-pae                    3.0.0+39                               Linux for modern PCs (meta-package)
```

Hope I got everything right.

Comment: I suspect that you have stumbled upon gnome 3

Comment: I suspect that you are right :) Do you have any suggestions to solve this ?

Comment: You have two separate issues, and it would be better to ask separate questions for them. To resolve the kernel issue, we need to know more: what is the exact kernel version and a description of your hardware; post the contents of `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and the output of `lspci` and `dpkg -l linux-image-\*` and we'll take it from there. To resolve the desktop issue, as Abhinav says, you're seeing Gnome 3; you need to know more: do you want to get used to Gnome 3, or find a familiar interface, or look for alternatives?

Comment: I do **not** recommend new-to-Linux users run Testing unless you have easy access to knowledgeable friends *and* have a lot of spare time.  If you really want to rescue your current system, [Debian-specific resources](http://www.debian.org/support) are a better option than playing 20-questions in comments on StackExchange for this sort of tech-support.  Take your pick from mailing lists, forums, or IRC (newbie beware).  Otherwise  my blanket suggestion, knowing nothing about your situation, is to back up your data and reinstall a clean, working copy of Stable.

Comment: @Gilles I posted everything you asked for. About the Gnome 3 I suppose I can live with it.

Comment: @jw013 I thought about reinstalling to clean copy of Stable but I decided to give the Testing a try and if something goes very bad I have the Stable in mind. Luckily for me I happened to have some friends that are very good with Linux, but I don't want to bother them at 2 AM. One of them said "I am using Stable for my servers but I think it's better to use the testing on my work station, because there is more fun with the new stuff that breaks all the time and you have to fix it :-)"

Comment: @jw013 Sorry for spamming here. In the IRC is this a channel - newbie beware ?

Comment: How much RAM do you have? If it's less than 4GB, switch to a non-PAE kernel. If it's 4GB or more, try an amd64 kernel. Also, remove `quiet` from the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` setting in `/etc/default/grub`, then run `update-grub`; this way you'll see kernel boot messages, and if the kernel locks up during boot, report the last few lines you see.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem with updating from stable to testing, and I think that good way is to reinstall testing from clean. Because when you update, you can get a lot of broken dependencies and your installed software, which worked with old libraries, can make problems. Besides, if you installed closed drivers fglrx, it was built for your previous version of kernel and can be broken with new. Also, pae-kernels can be a problem too. So, I recommend you to make a clean install if you don't want to fight with broken dependencies and drivers.